# If Then Else On Open VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi could someone help me in a very basic VBA formula?
I need an Excel tab to be visible or not depending on the name of the file.
So if the filename is called "CI Q (New_User)", the YourWeek tab is visible, otherwise it's hidden.

Tried this but doesnt work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   
 If (Wb.Name) Like "CI Q (New_User).xlsm" Then     
   Sheets("YourWeek").Visible = True
 Else
   Sheets("YourWeek").Visible = False       
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Wb` defined anywhere? Better use `Me.Name` ( without () ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private sub Workbook_Open()

   if Thisworkbook.Name = "CI Q (New_User).xlsm" then
      Sheets("YourWeek").Visible = True
   Else
      Sheets("YourWeek").Visible = False   
   end if

end sub
```

Comment: Or `Sheets("YourWeek").Visible = Thisworkbook.Name = "CI Q (New_User).xlsm"`